# Jquery UI call ajax from dialog and show the response in the content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my project I'm using jquery ui dialog.
Let me know if you can do something like this:

open dialog confirm ("are u sure? [yes] [no])

If no (close) - 
if yes (call ajax function and show response in the dialog)

I tried in this way but with no success.

```
  $('#confirm').dialog({
     resizable: false,
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
     'yes': function () {
        ajaxfunc();
    },
    'No': function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
```

});

```
 function ajaxfunc() {
    $.post("test.php", {
    id: 1
    }, function (data) {
        $(this).html(data);
    });
}
```

how could I do that? thanks

Comment: I think the this from "$(this).html(data);" will reffer to the window object, you should try selecting your element, maybe $('#confirm').html(data) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above in comments `this` has no context within `ajaxFunc()` the way you are calling it from within the callback function and will default to `window`.

Just pass reference to your function as the callback

```
   $('#confirm').dialog({   
     buttons: {
        'yes': ajaxfunc ,  
        'No': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }   
      /* other opts*/ 
    });
```

Since you are passing the function as reference, `this` will be the element the same way it is within your anonymous function callback

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7mQcDoKLJgrl4lhmZdTw?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#confirm').dialog(
{
           autoOpen: true, 
           buttons: {
              OK: function() {
                 ajaxfunc(k); 
              },
               Cancel:function(){$(this).dialog("close");}
           },
           resizable: 'true',
    modal:'true'

        }

);

 function ajaxfunc(k) {
$.post("test.php", {
id: 1
}, function (data) {
    $(k).html(data);
});
}
```